# PowerShell Pipeline very slow when run in jobs

Tags: powershell, performance

I have just by a change found out that this 15 PSJob oneliner runs really slow in PowerShell.

```
1..15 | %{ Start-Job -ScriptBlock { "Some random text" | Select -First 1 } } | Receive-Job -WriteJobInResults -wait #slow version
```

However, if the text is not sent over the pipe, the oneliner is fast as hell

```
1..15 | %{ Start-Job -ScriptBlock { "Some random text" } } | Receive-Job -WriteJobInResults -wait #fast version
```

Could anybody explain why this happens?

My PowerShell version

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.0.10586.672
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.672
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using.

Comment: Added that to the post

Comment: Can't explain it yet, but yes it does have a significant impact. Interesting bug

Comment: I wrapped it in `Measure-Command { }` and tried in Win PS v5.1.19041.1682 (and in PWSH v7.2.6) and both with and without the `Select -First 1` are taking the same time (around 8 seconds). So I guess the bug is now fixed.

Comment: THX for finding out!